# R: How to tidyr up data with var-val pairs concatenated in a single column

Tags: r, data-structures, concatenation, tidyr

I have already tried to get this solved at SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29120787/in-r-tidyr-split-and-swing-value-into-column-name-using-regex) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29134594/r-use-tidyr-to-clean-up-data-table-with-structural-missing-and-redundant-data) - of cause got good answers but realized this was only partial solutions to what I believe is a general problem: Often data has been organized as to have variables (the most interestingly ones obviously) as one column per variable and then a final column where several variable-value pairs have been put together. I have been struggling for a general way to swing the last columns variables into separate columns and should this tidying up data not be a job for `tidyr`?

```
require(dplyr)
require(stringr)

data <- 
      data.frame(
        shoptype=c("A","B","B"),
        city=c("bah", "bah", "slah"),
        sale=c("type cheese; price 200", "type ham; price 150","type cheese; price 100" )) %>%
      tbl_df()

> data
Source: local data frame [3 x 3]

  shoptype city                   sale
1        A  bah type cheese; price 200
2        B  bah    type ham; price 150
3        B slah type cheese; price 100
```

Here we have info about some shops in some cities with a concatenated column where variables are separated with ";" and var-val with space.
One would like an output as this:

```
    shoptype    city    type    price
1   A   bah cheese  200
2   B   bah ham 150
3   B   slah    cheese  100
```

When all rows a unique one can do (see the linked SO questions)

```
require(plyr)
require(dplyr)
require(stringr)
require(tidyr)  
data %>%
  mutate(sale = str_split(as.character(sale), "; ")) %>%
  unnest(sale) %>%
  mutate(sale = str_trim(sale)) %>%
  separate(sale, into = c("var", "val")) %>%
  spread(var, val)
```

But if we change second row shoptype to "A" we get an error because of this. Like:

```
data2 <- 
  data.frame(
    shoptype=c("A","A","B"),
    city=c("bah", "bah", "slah"),
    sale=c("type cheese; price 200", "type ham; price 150","type cheese; price 100" )) %>%
  tbl_df()
data2 %>%
  mutate(sale = str_split(as.character(sale), "; ")) %>%
  unnest(sale) %>%
  mutate(sale = str_trim(sale)) %>%
  separate(sale, into = c("var", "val")) %>%
  spread(var, val)
Error: Duplicate identifiers for rows (2, 4), (1, 3)
```

I tried to solve this (again see linked SO answers) with a unique id:

```
data2 %>%
  mutate(sale = str_split(as.character(sale), "; ")) %>%
  unnest(sale) %>%
  mutate(sale = str_trim(sale),
         v0=rownames(.)) %>%
  separate(sale, into = c("var", "val")) %>%
  spread(var, val)
Source: local data frame [6 x 5]

  shoptype city v0 price   type
1        A  bah  1    NA cheese
2        A  bah  2   200     NA
3        A  bah  3    NA    ham
4        A  bah  4   150     NA
5        B slah  5    NA cheese
6        B slah  6   100     NA
```

Which gives structural missing data that I cannot figure out how to gather as described in my desired output above.

I guess Im really missing something that would be within the scope of tidyr (I hope!).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the secondary ID before splitting:

```
data2 %>%
  group_by(shoptype, city) %>%
  mutate(id2 = sequence(n())) %>%
  mutate(sale = str_split(as.character(sale), "; ")) %>%
  unnest(sale) %>%
  mutate(sale = str_trim(sale)) %>%
  separate(sale, into = c("var", "val")) %>%
  spread(var, val)
# Source: local data frame [3 x 5]
# 
#   shoptype city id2 price   type
# 1        A  bah   1   200 cheese
# 2        A  bah   2   150    ham
# 3        B slah   1   100 cheese
```

The code can be made a little more compact if you use some of the functions from my "splitstackshape" package:

```
as.data.frame(data2) %>%
  getanID(c("shoptype", "city")) %>%
  cSplit("sale", ";", "long") %>%
  cSplit("sale", " ") %>%
  spread(sale_1, sale_2)
#    shoptype city .id price   type
# 1:        A  bah   1   200 cheese
# 2:        A  bah   2   150    ham
# 3:        B slah   1   100 cheese
```

Comment: Like Ananda Mahto's the best; mainly because its more general in that you dont need to know the variables of the var-val column. And good point with the id before split - it was the key issue, I completely missed it before.

Answer (score 6):

I don't see a need to use `tidyr::unnest` and `tidyr::gather`. Here's an alternative solution that focuses on `stringr::str_replace` and `tidyr::separate`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(tidyr)

data2 %>%
  mutate(
    sale = str_replace(sale, "type ", ""),
    sale = str_replace(sale, " price ", "")
    ) %>%
  separate(sale, into = c("type", "price"), sep = ";") 

# Source: local data frame [3 x 4]

#   shoptype city   type price
# 1        A  bah cheese   200
# 2        A  bah    ham   150
# 3        B slah cheese   100
```

Comment: I think you have your "price" and "type" mixed up in `separate`, but +1 for an approach that doesn't require splitting in the traditional sense.

Comment: Slightly shorter if you use `mutate(sale = str_replace(sale, "type |price ", ""))` but a nice answer already.

Comment: Of course, it would not work if one of the rows had the items swapped, for instance, `"price 150; type ham"`...

Comment: @docendodiscimus - I like your variation, but that would require `str_replace_all`

Comment: hmm, I would just use sub/gsub anyway, but okay.

Comment: @AnandaMahto- Good catch on "price" and "type" mixup. It's fixed.

Answer (score 4):

Two good answers above, but thought that this is a pretty nice situation for `extract`

```
data2 %>%
  extract(sale, c("type", "price"), "type (.+); price (.+)", convert = TRUE)
```